# Unlist data from specific data frame

Tags: r, list

I am downloading data with the procedure described below :

```
library(IMFData)
IFS.available.codes <- DataStructureMethod("WoRLD")

# Available dimension code
names(IFS.available.codes)

# Define period
databaseID <- "WoRLD"
startdate = "2010-01-01"
enddate = "2021-12-31"
checkquery = FALSE

country_names<-IFS.available.codes$CL_AREA_WoRLD$CodeValue

# Select indicator and country
queryfilter <- list(CL_FREA = "", CL_AREA_WoRLD = c("DE","FR"),  CL_INDICATOR_WoRLD="RTGSE_RM_GDP")
data <- CompactDataMethod(databaseID, queryfilter, startdate, enddate, 
                                     checkquery)
```

After executing this procedure, I downloaded a file titled data. You can see the structure below:

[image]

So in this structure are present data in list format (column **Obs**). So can anybody help me how to convert this file to normal data.frame without list inside ?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**  To add the Ref_Area column we could do it like this.
Here we have a list of list. With data$Obs we get the first list of the list. Within this we access the first data frame with `data$Obs[1]` and the `REF_AREA` with the same concept. The same is applied to the second list:

Here the true strength of `bind_rows` is in action:
"The `...` argument is used to combine data frames.

Each argument can either be a `data frame`, a `list` that could be a `data frame`, or a `list of data frames`. Columns are matched by name, and any missing columns will be filled with NA"

```
library(dplyr)

data1 <- data$Obs[1] %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(REF_AREA = data$`@REF_AREA`[1])

data2 <- data$Obs[2] %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  mutate(REF_AREA = data$`@REF_AREA`[2])

bind_rows(data1, data2)
```

```
 @TIME_PERIOD       @OBS_VALUE @SOURCE_COVERAGE_AND_ACCOUNTING_BASIS REF_AREA
1          2010 2.28329849243164                        OECD | General       FR
2          2011 2.34540510177612                        OECD | General       FR
3          2012 2.36545276641846                        OECD | General       FR
4          2013 2.45967602729797                        OECD | General       FR
5          2014  2.4561140537262                        OECD | General       FR
6          2015 2.56362009048462                        OECD | General       FR
7          2016 2.62368679046631                        OECD | General       FR
8          2017   2.678546667099                        OECD | General       FR
9          2018 2.73174643516541                        OECD | General       FR
10         2019 2.65045738220215                        OECD | General       FR
11         2010 2.47379493713379                        OECD | General       DE
12         2011 2.46320843696594                        OECD | General       DE
13         2012 2.36301183700562                        OECD | General       DE
14         2013 2.29857540130615                        OECD | General       DE
15         2014 2.22382760047913                        OECD | General       DE
16         2015 2.15882730484009                        OECD | General       DE
17         2016 2.07082581520081                        OECD | General       DE
18         2017 2.03568243980408                        OECD | General       DE
19         2018 1.96385836601257                        OECD | General       DE
20         2019 1.90556669235229                        OECD | General       DE
```

**First answer:**
We could do somthing like this using `bind_rows`:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(data$Obs)
```

```
  @TIME_PERIOD       @OBS_VALUE @SOURCE_COVERAGE_AND_ACCOUNTING_BASIS
1          2010 2.28329849243164                        OECD | General
2          2011 2.34540510177612                        OECD | General
3          2012 2.36545276641846                        OECD | General
4          2013 2.45967602729797                        OECD | General
5          2014  2.4561140537262                        OECD | General
6          2015 2.56362009048462                        OECD | General
7          2016 2.62368679046631                        OECD | General
8          2017   2.678546667099                        OECD | General
9          2018 2.73174643516541                        OECD | General
10         2019 2.65045738220215                        OECD | General
11         2010 2.47379493713379                        OECD | General
12         2011 2.46320843696594                        OECD | General
13         2012 2.36301183700562                        OECD | General
14         2013 2.29857540130615                        OECD | General
15         2014 2.22382760047913                        OECD | General
16         2015 2.15882730484009                        OECD | General
17         2016 2.07082581520081                        OECD | General
18         2017 2.03568243980408                        OECD | General
19         2018 1.96385836601257                        OECD | General
20         2019 1.90556669235229                        OECD | General
```

Comment: @TarJe One column is missing with the title REF_AREA . This column contains short names of the countries such as FR and DE.